# How best to adjust the colour of different parts of an (all raster) image that are on the same layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

[image]

I am attempting to experiment with different colours for the grey, orange and pink areas of this image. They all appear with no separation on a single layer.

So far I've tried selecting and separating them on to their own layers, then adjusting the hue/saturation of those layers. This did not work, however, as I only succeeded in adjusting the entire image.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? **Is there a easier way than using hue/saturation and adjustment layers? I can't quite figure out how the resulting colours correspond, so it would be easier if I could select the colours I wished to use directly...**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an **Adjustment Layer** to adjust the hue and saturation non-destructively:

[image: hsi adjustment layer]

> To confine the effects of an adjustment layer to specific image layers, select the image layers, choose Layer > New > Group From Layers, and change the Mode from Pass Through to any other blending mode. Then place the adjustment layer at the top of the layer group.

Help Docs: [**Photoshop / 
Adjustment and fill layers**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-787ba.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, it seemed to work. That said, is adjusting the hue on separate layers the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I'm not familiar with adjustments layers and can't really seem to get the hang of the hue-colour relationship. Would there be a way to do it by using hex codes or directly selecting the colours, for example? Thank you.

Comment: @zakgottlieb you could alternatively do a Color Overlay as a Layer Style and set the Blend Mode to Color (or something besides Normal that works for you)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend JohnB's approach as the best approach, but an interesting alternative is to use the color range to mask the buttons, accessed through **Select** → **Color Range...**

Because these are really distinct bright colors color range does a good job of selecting the specific colors you want. You would have to set the tolerance somewhat low and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Select</kbd> different colors in the image. This creates a selection of your buttons. You could then create a copy of the layer and use the selection as mask. I would feather the mask slightly in the **Properties** window as well.

[image: Color Range]

You could then use the **Channel Mixer** and your masked layer as a clipping mask for the adjustment

[image: Channel Mixer]

As you can see some of the value is being lost in the midtones, but it is still pretty neat if you ask me.